# running all http request at one time in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

[image]

In my test plan after login i am clicking on link, that link makes call to 10+ different services to show data. With current test plan all those 10+ service goes in sequential format i wan't know if there is a way i can call all of them at same time. I can create multiple thread to achieve this, but as i have more links  to add and it will create more thread and more login instance. Just wanted to get suggestions if i can do something using logical controllers available in Jmeter?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately each thread always runs sequentially (the only exception is retrieval of embedded resources in HTTP sampler, but this is now useful in your case). There are a few options:

1. Use multiple threads with Random Order Controller or Random Controller
2. Use Thread Groups running on parallel. And in order to not duplicate your code in each thread group, use [Module Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller)
3. I saw [jmeter-parellarel-request](https://github.com/franz-see/jmeter-parellarel-request), but I have no experience with it, so cannot recommend

Comment: Thanks. I am trying 3 option you suggest but its only getting executed once. Need to do more research.

Comment: I usually go with option 2, since it's the closest to reality. There's also an option 4, but that one is complicated: the option is to create your own sampler, and do whatever you want there.

Comment: Module option is again not same, i have 8 different calls which i need to make at same time, now if i consider i created 8 modules they will still not run in parallel right? Let me know if my understanding is wrong..

Comment: No, you make 8 Thread Groups, and configure your test plan to run them in parallel. Instead of duplicating your 8 calls, you configure each thread group to run the same module (which includes your 8 calls) using Module Controller.

Comment: Thanks, Agree with thread we might not even need modular controller. But i was more trying inside single thread to make my reporting easy.

Answer (score 3):

As per the design, JMeter does not support sending multiple HTTP calls at the same time for a single user. It will send them sequentially only! So, you might not be able to simulate AJAX requests exactly as the browser does.

However JMeter has Beanshell sampler / JSR223 sampler through which you can implement that yourself.

See [this example](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter).

The approach might be ok for few threads/users. When i tried to follow similar approach for more than 20 threads, I got an Out of Memory error for a very simple test as it has to create multiple threads to simulate AJAX calls for each user.

Comment: Thanks for response, i think JSR223 will have limitation, i wouldn't be able to do Parameterization to manipulate data? Please correct me if i am wrong...